# Attached and dettached entities Hibernate JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Wel i've been working on an app, and i had to use Data base, but in one part i have something like this

```java
ArrayList<User> users = (ArrayList<User>) manager.createQuery("FROM User").getResultList();
```

and this recover a list of users, but someway they're all detached, so when i try to do some action i have to re-attach them.

```java
ArrayList<House> houses = (ArrayList<House>)manager.createQuery("From House").getResultList();

        for (House h : houses) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode house = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
            house.setUserObject(h);
            begin.add(house);
            for (Area a : h.getAreas()) {
                DefaultMutableTreeNode area = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
                area.setUserObject(a);
                house.add(area);
                for (Room r : a.getRooms()) {
                    DefaultMutableTreeNode room = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
                    room.setUserObject(r);
                    area.add(room);
                    for (Device d : r.getDevices()) {
                        DefaultMutableTreeNode device = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
                        device.setUserObject(d);
                        room.add(device);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Also i have that code above, but those are currently attached and not if i explicitly tell hibernate to dettached them...

How do i tell hibernate to attach or dettach an entities by default?

Comment: Do you want to detach all entities, or looking for config which will create entities in detached manner. If prior, then use entityManager.clear(), for latter during inheritance viz. @OneToOne(CascadeType.DETACH)

Comment: The code you have provided is very abstract, the manager seems to be handling hibernate session and attach/dettach, so your question is little broad, please add what you want to do and what you already have.